# Algolia search, displaying all results even when radius set

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, algolia

So I want to search by lat and lng within 5km radius, despite limiting hits per page to 10, it is still displaying all markers on map and there are 96, why isn't this working properly?

```
var APPLICATION_ID = '**';
var SEARCH_ONLY_API_KEY = '**';
var INDEX_NAME = 'locations';
var PARAMS = { hitsPerPage: 10 };
// Client + Helper initialization
var algolia = algoliasearch(APPLICATION_ID, SEARCH_ONLY_API_KEY);
var algoliaHelper = algoliasearchHelper(algolia, INDEX_NAME, PARAMS);
algoliaHelper.setQueryParameter('aroundLatLng', '53.552472, -2.807663');
algoliaHelper.setQueryParameter('aroundRadius', 5000);
algoliaHelper.search();
// Map initialization
var markers = [];
//alert("heelo");
algoliaHelper.on('result', function(content) {
    renderHits(content);
  var i;
  // Add the markers to the map
  for (i = 0; i < content.hits.length; ++i) {
    var hit = content.hits[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: hit.longitude, lng: hit.latitude},
      map: map,
      label: hit.slug,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }
});
function renderHits(content) {
  $('#container').html(JSON.stringify(content, null, 2));
}

});
```

How a very weird reason if I delete:

```
algoliaHelper.setQueryParameter('aroundLatLng', '53.552472, -2.807663');
algoliaHelper.setQueryParameter('aroundRadius', 5000);
algoliaHelper.search();
```

It still brings back all records, does anyone have a clue why is this happening?

Comment: do alert( content.hits.length) what is the number?

Comment: Can you try to add algoliaHelper.setQueryParameter('hitsPerPage', 10);?